# How to style for my a element in the div class ="contact-information"?

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<section id="contact">
<div class="contact-informatformation ">
  <h1>If you have any comments or suggestions,please contact us by:
    <a href="https://facebook.com/freecodecamp" target="_blank" class="btn contact-details"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i> facebook </a>
</div> 
  </section>
```

CSS

```
.contact-information > a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

I am trying to make the a element in my div class contact-information to be black, I have tried to use CSS selector `.contact-information > a` and `.contact-information  a` but it does not work, and do you know the difference between these two selectors?

Comment: typo: `.contact-informatformation > a { ... }`

Comment: `contact-informatformation` != `.contact-information`

Comment: Where is your closing `</h1>` tag?

Comment: See [MDN's article on the child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) to discover the difference. The space is called [the descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, you got the class name wrong, I fixed it in your HTML code which is supposed to be `contact-information`. Next, you forgot to close the `<h1>` tag. Lastly, you are trying to access a child of the `div` with class `contact-information` which is not an immediate child. For that, it's a child of `h1` which is a child of the `div`. You can access it as `.contact-information>*>a { ... }`. This selects the next immediate `a` child. To select child of any level, directly use `.contact-information a { ... }`

```css
.contact-information>*>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <div class="contact-information">
    <h1>
      If you have any comments or suggestions,please contact us by:
      <a href="https://facebook.com/freecodecamp" target="_blank" class="btn contact-details">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>facebook
      </a>
    </h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The more efficient method would be just `.contact-information a`. The selector this answer uses selects any and all children of elements with the class "contact-information" and searches those for descendants that are anchors, rather than just searching for those descendants for those elements directly.

Comment: Also, typo questions should just be closed (for flagged for closure) rather than being answered.

Comment: Is my answer wrong @HereticMonkey? I had a different approach than yours, but that doesn't mean it was wrong, it worked hence it was right. Also the question doesn't only get solved by the typos, it needs some other thing too

Comment: Just because an answer works does not guarantee that it will not be downvoted. The answer must be useful as well. This answer is not useful because it answers a typo question, and could simply use code presented in the original question (namely, `.contact-information a`)  to provide a more efficient solution while also teaching the OP about the difference between child and descendant combinators, rather than confusing the two by combining them.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS needs to be:

```
.contact-informatformation > a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

You misspelled the class name.

Comment: Please do not answer questions which come from simple typos or mistakes like this. These are not helpful for anyone other than the OP, and therefore do not fit the mission of Stack Overflow, which is to be a repository of high-quality questions and answers that help multiple developers.